# Why I can raise flags if I am flag-banned?

Tags: support, flags, flag-ban

Sometimes I raise flags that maybe are not accepted by a moderator. This is the normal behavior of Stack Overflow. And I receive the message that I cannot post flags for one week.

But still I am able to create new flags, remove it as usual. Is this the expected behavior? I assume that the idea is that I cannot assign any flags.

[image]

On the previous image, you can see that I am banned, but still I have created two flags today (few hours ago). Is this the expected behavior?

Now, I am not able to set flags again. Not sure why because I have not new declined flag today.

[image]

Some information that can be useful:

- I have been banned at the end of past week. Then the 7 days period is not finishing today.
- I was able to set few flags today early (questions are from today). But I am not able to set them again.
- I am not able to set flags on questions neither in answers. That is what I expect.

In fact, the current behavior is what I expect. But is clear that I have raised today two flags (and one of them also has been used by a moderator).

Comment: Or does the banned flags works different for questions that for answers. I mean, maybe I am banned only to flags questions but not answers?

Comment: "currently" != "few hours ago"

Comment: These Flag bans are automatic based on a 7 day sliding window, counting helpful and declined flags. A moderator or a review action on a single flag can put you in a flag ban but if you're on the edge you could well be un-banned a few hours later.

Comment: I have updated the question with some extra information. Now I am not able to set flags again, that is interesting because the only current flag I have set today has been found "helpful".

Comment: Any flag that got declined these 7 days contribute. You can have had a flag declined you raised days or weeks ago.

Comment: Being banned from raising flags is not normal behavior of Stack Overflow. Occasional declined or disputed flags are normal, but getting enough to be banned is not, and should not, be normal behavior.

Comment: Close "flags" (one shown in the post) and normal flags are different... I suspect (no link to confirm) that flag ban does not apply to the close "flags".

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think OP uses word "normal" as "this is normal for me on SO" but rather "that's exactly how SO is expected to behave when X happen".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Could be. My statement still stands either way ;).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov is right. I am telling that is the normal behaviour from SO "as expected", not that SO bans me all days. Nevertheless, the point is not if I must be banned or not, or if my flags are good or not. The point is that I have raised flags meanwhile I am banned.

Comment: @KingMidas you should try to raise regular flag like NAA (not "close flag") - I bet it would be blocked. [Edit] the question with result of the experiment. Side note: bans are site-specific so make sure to try on the site where you are banned for flagging, I think even main and meta considered different for bans.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov in my first picture is shown how the flags are created in the same site where I am banned, and also the flags on the second picture when I am not allowed to raise are exactly same portal (everything stackoverflow, not meta). Take in mind that my tag originally was "bug"  due to -in my point of view- is not the expected behavior. Now I am not banned any more and is hard to reproduce.

Comment: @KingMidas In order for there to be a ban, you have to have had >= 10 flags resolved in the last 7 days. It's quite possible for a flag marked "helpful" to move you from 9 resolved flags to 10 resolved flags in the last 7 days. If you also have too many flags which have been declined in that time, then the ban will be resumed. This can happen multiple times as other flags resolved as "helpful" roll out of the 7 day sliding window. Once enough of the declined flags roll out of the 7 day sliding window, this will no longer happen.