# Triage Queue disappeared but others are working as expected

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

I already have an experience of being temporarily suspended from reviewing, and I think I learned useful lessons after carefully reading *how to review* per each review type; however, when that suspension happened earlier, I was suspended from reviewing **all** queues.

Now, I have 3 declined flags in my Flag Summary:

- one for a spam flag (still have no clue why it was rejected, although I cannot see the post I flagged anymore on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128776/android-resource-compilation-failed-android-studio-4-0-1/) question);
- one for a [very low quality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63980926/1553537) flag (unsure, if that is not a very low quality);
- one for a [not an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63969576/1553537) (I might agree that this can be considered as an answer, even though, frankly speaking, I find it debatable, that [this text only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63969576/1553537) is an answer, as back in the days, I was warned for the contrary - that I have clicked on "Requires Editing" on this kind of post, and I got the suspension, that I should've had marked that as "Unsalvageable").

If someone will enlighten me about these three flags, I would be thankful; however, as the title implies, my main question is the following:

> Now, only Triage review queue has disappeared from my Review Queues. I am still able to review other types, but Triage is not visible after I clicked on it (it was visible before this click, and disappeared - after) and decided to do some reviews.

Shortly: Previously I was suspended from all the reviews, now Triage is not available.

Any clues what exactly has happened?

Comment: You might've been flag-banned

Comment: For info, the deleted post you did flag as spam -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ae2w.png Non english, so certainly VLQ but not a spam per se. There is no link to any product nor anything seemingly "promoting" any product or service.

Comment: @Kaiido that's what I thought as well.. I, sort of, remember that somewhere I read that blatantly off-topic posts can/should be flagged as spam, but seems like this is wrong assumption, and VLQ should be the one to chose in that case. Thank you.

Comment: @Zoe no, I'm not flag-banned *per-se*; however, when I try to flag something, I have a *Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!* warning. Yet, flagging is still available.

Comment: @Zoe by the way, a side-note question: doesn't *Review* privilege override *flag-ban* (if flag-ban is imposed) when you're doing the *reviews*, and not flagging - as such? or any Triage review is implicitly a flag?

Comment: Without flags, you are a less effective reviewer. On many posts that are flag-worthy you would not be able to take the appropriate action. It makes sense to block you from reviewing until you get your flag-privileges restored, IMO.

Comment: If you've spent or unable to do an action that is part of a review task for a queue, the review queue will not be accessible to you. As an example, if you've spent all your up/down votes, you will not have access to First Posts or Late Answers, but still have access to Triage. I'm a bit curious how you can have the reversed access though.

Comment: @Scratte yeah, I'm aware of that, but I'm ordinarily doing any other type of review. Also, I'm not flag-banned, I just have a warning I mentioned above; yet, Triage is disappeared (strange, really..). Yet, I think, even if I would've been flag-banned (which I'm not), I should still be able to review those with those options, that do not need *flag*, per se.

Comment: I'm not sure the argument is valid @GiorgiTsiklauri because if I've spent all my 40 up/down votes on a day while still have all my 100 flags, I could potentially still review Late Answers, just skipping all the ones I should have downvoted, but the system will not let me enter the queue because I am unable to perform one of the review actions. The only thing that puzzles me is that you still have access to First Posts and Late Answers.

Comment: @Scratte but what about the point that I'm not flag-banned? this is something which I keep repeating again and again.. :) not only about Late Answers, but generally, for any other type. I'm reviewing and flagging w/o any obstacle. The only review queue that has disappeared is Triage.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri What message do you get if you navigate to an active review directly (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27207862))

Comment: @Nick "Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them!". But not the "you are temporarily suspended.." one, which I got previously when I was suspended.

Comment: Question to those who voted for the closure with "Needs more focus". How else on the earth this can be more focused?

Comment: Try visiting the main queue page: https://stackoverflow.com/review. Does it tell you what the problem is (which sounds like, that you're flag banned)?

Comment: @CertainPerformance no, it's looking how it is usually.. absolutely same. It doesn't tell me anything like that. I do everything as I usually do, and again.. I'm not flag-banned.. I can flag, the only catch is that flagging window contains warning, that I better review my declined flags, as some got declined.

Comment: Curious, maybe there's something else going on. By any chance, are you out of close votes for the day? I know that some queues stop being usable when you're out of certain vote types.

Comment: @CertainPerformance "You have 48 votes left today" - says the flagging page, when I open it for the closure vote.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri On the "focus" comment- you start your post with "I was banned from review," then dive into 3 declined flags you disagree with, and then redirect your post again to what you described as your "main question," which has little to do with the previous two topics. That's... a bit unfocused.

Comment: @zcoop98 1) where have I said that I disagree with the declines? 2) where have I said, that I was banned?; 3) haven't I clearly stated, that the question is what I write as a question? and haven't I just appended those three review posts for the clarity? wouldn't not mentioning any post, at all, have caused a bit of confusion? have you read my question carefully?

Comment: It is better to back up claims (e.g. being rude) with evidence. I would recommend to have a notes file and note down everything (incl. the URL) that you might think you would need to reference in the future (and/or make notes that allows you to easily find it). (I "tag" my notes with "Stack Overflow" and other keywords on a single line in order to be able to quickly locate a particular note (by [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) or a text editor's 'find' facility).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I actually never thought I would have found that useful.. as I never wanted to (so to say) push the case against anyone.. but after this, I think you are right. I should have done that.. and it's pity I haven't. Also, in some cases, comments get deleted afterwards..

Comment: (One lesson I learned was to include *[the date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)* for each note (either current date or "publication" date), for example as part of the "tag" line. This provides important context and is useful when rearranging notes (say, in priority/importance order instead of date/entry order). I have [text templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit) in [UltraEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) and [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany) that outputs a skeleton note, including the current date.)

Comment: Lol.. this is now really really strange. I now have my Triage reviews back. Just after few hours..

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can see

1. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63969445/1839482) answer has been deleted and only 10k+ users can see it now. It's not spam because it's not trying to promote anything. It's gibberish and should be flagged as VLQ.
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63980926/1839482) answer is not very low quality because there is some kind of explanation other than the link. Does not really qualify as link only answer. It's better not to flag it either as NAA or VLQ.
3. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63969576/1839482) answer is a valid *attempt to answer* and hence not eligible for NAA flag.

As [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286417/1839482) answer says folks are blocked from Triage review when they are flag-banned.

Comment: Important part here: I'm not flag-banned. I just have a warning, as I mention above, yet I still can *flag* posts for different reasons. I agree on the review points you explain here.

Comment: This might give you some clue https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391854/why-i-can-raise-flags-if-i-am-flag-banned

Comment: In the flag summary section of your profile you do not see any message about ban?

Comment: Again, I'm not banned. I see the warning, that I might review if I really want to flag this, as I have some declined flags recently.. but I can flag, and I'm not banned from it.